# invokeLater is not getting called

Tags: swing, user-interface, thread-safety

I'm working on an alarm application. I'm using SwingUtilities.invokeLater method to call my UI for snooze function. But when I run it I noticed that SwingUtilities.invokeLater function is not being called. Please help me with this problem

```
public class IsTime {  
int hrs;  
int min;  
int sec;  
GregorianCalendar clk=new GregorianCalendar();  
Calendar gtl= Calendar.getInstance();  

    mp3 mix=new mp3();  



    public void makeReady(int h,int m,int s,String ampm){  

    Calendar c1=Calendar.getInstance();  
    c1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,h);  
    c1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, m);  
    c1.set(Calendar.SECOND,s);  


    if("PM".equals(ampm)){  
        c1.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);  
        if(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.AM_PM)==Calendar.PM){  

            if(c1.after(Calendar.getInstance())){  
                check(c1);  
            }  
            c1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)+1);  

            check(c1);  

        }  
    }  
    if(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.AM_PM)==Calendar.AM){  
            if(c1.after(Calendar.getInstance())){  
                check(c1);  
            }  

            c1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)+1);  

            check(c1);  
        }  
    if(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.AM_PM)==Calendar.PM){  
        c1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)+1);  
        check(c1);  
    }  
}  
public void check(Calendar ch){  
        while(!(Calendar.getInstance().after(ch))){//this line checks if it is time to sound alarm  
        }  

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){//here is my invokelater method  

                public void run(){  
                    System.out.println("git to invoke");  
                 new Snooze();  

                }  

    });  
            mix.start();  


}  
public void makeReady(int mis){  
        Calendar sz=Calendar.getInstance();  
        sz.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);  
        sz.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE)+mis);  
        check(sz);  
    }  


}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line is really not the proper way to perform "waiting" operation:

```
while (!Calendar.getInstance().after(ch)) {// this line checks if it is time to sound alarm
    }
```

but rather do:

```
Thread.sleep(ch.getTimeInMillis()-System.currentTimeMillis());
```

(and you should make sure it is positive). As it stands now, your code will continously evaluate if it is time which will probably kill your CPU.

For your `invokeLater()`, it is hard to tell without a proper fully-working example (an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)). Try to put a log right before the call and see if it pops in your console.